# CLI routing not working with @hug.extend_api()

Tags: python, python-3.x, hug

I'm trying to use `@hug.extend_api()` for CLI routes but it's not working.

Calling `hug -f run.py -c something`, the command list is empty. The same code works fine for HTTP routing.

This is my main script (`run.py`):

```
import hug
from apitest import api


@hug.extend_api()
def apis():
    return [api]
```

This is `apitest/api.py`:

```
import hug


@hug.cli()  # cli route doesn't work
@hug.get('/')  # get route works fine
def root():
    return 'hello'
```

Comment: I just reported this issue in https://github.com/timothycrosley/hug/issues/744